# One more question on biharmonic functions

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $w$ be a function $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ with the following properties:

- $w$ is globally $\alpha$-Hölder continuous, $\alpha \in (0,1)$;
- $w$ is biharmonic on $C=\{w>0\}$;
- $w$ is subharmonic on $\mathbb R^n$;
- $w\geq 0$;
- the set $C$ is not empty.

Question: Is it true that $\lambda(\partial C)=0$, where $\lambda$
is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$?

I would appreciate proof strategies and useful references.